# Quill editor output does not show line break

Tags: html, css

In quill editor i have following html

```
<p>Hello</p>
<h2><br><h2>
<h2>How are your</h2>
<p>Something</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>After empty line</p>
```

It should show the empty line where ever `empty tag` contain `br` tag
as below

```
<p>Hello</p>
<h2><br><h2>
<h2>How are your</h2>
<p>Something</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>After empty line</p>
```

but after saving the content to database and retrieving back and display on web pages does not display empty line.Can anyone tell me what should i do.

Comment: what's `p2` ? ...

Comment: sorry it is p tag

Answer (score -1):

What I would do (even though I'm more of a year 2000 person not a 2018 person) is to use style sheets then you can format each block of HTML so that there is spacing around it. Here's code to help you get started:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Something</title>
<style type="text/css">
.morespace {padding-bottom: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="morespace">Hello</p>
<h2>How are your</h2>
<p class="morespace">Something</p>
<p>After empty line</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, a 20 pixel space will be added to the bottom of the HTML that contains class=morespace.

You can also use margin-bottom instead of padding-bottom if you like. and you can also change 20px to whatever size space you want.

and if the Quill program doesn't cooperate, always test in a modern web browser that people will use for best results.

Comment: The answer not at all about quill editor. You probably don't understand the question. It's more about quill editor ocnfiguration. Indeed, i have the same problem as Auhtor. 

Content retrieved from DB (some empty lines) is not shown in editor, it cuts it out during input, but outputs empty elements to be saved into DB.